# find $p$, $q$ such that $f$ is differentiable at zero

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to understand tasks like that
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} q+\sin(px)+qx &\text{for } x\ge0 \\ \frac{-1}{x\sin(x)} + \frac{\cos(x)}{x\sin(x)} &\text{for } x\in (-\pi,0)   \end{cases}$$
On my lecture I had theorem that
 $f$ is differentiable at zero if and only if exists finite:
$$ \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}= f'(a) $$

### My current way of thinking

Ok, after small discussion in comments, I think that these conditions should be fulfilled:
1. $$ \lim_{h\rightarrow0^-} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0^+} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} $$ what is equal to:
 $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}f'(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} f'(x) $$

2. Function should be continuous: 
    
   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} f(x) = f(0)$$

### My current problem

I am trying to solve this with differential quotient but I stucked
$$ \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} $$
there is a problem:(

Comment: Start by getting continuity at $0$.  Take the limits from the left and the right (in terms of $p$ and $q$).

Comment: I wrote that in topic

Comment: The lazy way of doing this is just by considering two things: continuity and $f’_+ (0)=f’_-(0)$, where $f_+$ is $f$ for $x \geq 0$ and $f_-$ for $x \in (-\pi,0)$. And indeed all the things need to be limits.

Comment: Why lazy? What do you mean by that?

Comment: I edited topic - can you look at this again? I don't want solution, only I want to be sure about my way of thinking

Comment: Just a little comment on the difference between taking the limit, for example, $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0+} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$ and the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0+} f'(x_0)$. These two limits are equal **if** the latter exists. If it doesn't, nothing can be said about the former. And you need to calculate it explicitly.

Comment: Are you sure? I think that i can understand this questions as "We know that $f$ is differentiable - find $p$, $q$ "

Comment: "Are you sure" was addressed to me? Yes you are right, the requirement is to find values of the parameters so that etc. My comment is still valid. When verifying differentiability in $x_0$ it might be useful to recall that existence of the limit of the derivative function in $x_0$ is a sufficient but not necessary condition. Take the usual $f(x) = x^2 \sin (1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x=0$ as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $p,q$ and assume $f'(0)$ exists. Then $f$ is continuous at $0.$ Because $f(0)=q,$ we must have $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=q.$ But

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\cos x-1}{x\sin x} = -\frac{1}{2}.$$

Therefore $q= -1/2.$

Now take $x>0$ and consider

$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}= \frac{-1/2 +\sin (px) -x/2 +1/2}{x} = \frac{\sin (px) - x/2}{x}.$$

The limit of this from the right is $p-1/2.$ This is the derivative of $f$ from the right at $0.$

Thus the derivative from the left equals $p-1/2.$ To find out what that implies, we look at the difference quotient from the left:

$$\frac{(\cos x-1)/(x\sin x)-(-1/2)}{x}= \frac{\cos x-1+(x\sin x)/2}{x^2\sin x}.$$

Using $\cos x = 1-x^2/2 + O(x^4)$ and $\sin x = x + O(x^3)$ shows the above equals

$$\frac{O(x^4)}{x^2\sin x}\to 0.$$

Thus the derivative from the left is $0.$ Therefore $p-1/2 = 0.$ So $p=1/2.$

Summary: Fixing $p,q$ and assuming $f'(0)$ exists, we showed $q=-1/2, p=1/2.$ We're not quite done though. Now we have to reason in the other direction: Assuming $q=-1/2, p=1/2,$ it follows that $f'(0)$ exists. This is simple, and I'll leave this to you for now.

Comment: Ok, so if I assume that $ f'(a)$ exists, (a) will I find all "possible" (but they may be wrong) values? (b) If I want to check if these values are correct,  I should  put them to $ \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} $ and check if derivative exists, is that right? @zhw.

Comment: Right.  It's an iff statement. Thus we must show $f'(0)$ exists $\implies q=-1/2,p=1/2$ and $q=-1/2,p=1/2\implies f'(0)$ exists. I showed the first $\implies.$

Comment: Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 3):

First observe that

$$ \frac{\cos(x) - 1}{x \sin(x)} = \frac{\cos(x) - 1}{x^2} \cdot \frac{x}{\sin(x)} \longrightarrow -\frac 1 2 $$
for $x \to 0$. Moreover, it holds 
$q + \sin(px)  + qx \to q$. So since we need continuity of $f$ in the first place, one obtains $q = -\frac 1 2$.

Now calculate the left and the right derivate in $0$ for the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} -\frac 1 2+\sin(px)- \frac 1 2 x &\text{for } x\geq 0, \\ \frac{-1}{x\sin(x)} + \frac{\cos(x)}{x\sin(x)} &\text{for } x\in (-\pi,0).   \end{cases}$$

If you want $f$ to be differentiable in $x = 0$ you need to have $\lim_{h \to -0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to +0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}$. This relation yields you then all possible values for $p$.

Comment: Ok, but there I have problem: $\lim_{h \to -0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} $ - There I can't use derivate - I should calculate this from $  \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} $

Comment: And that makes me trouble, I am not able to finish calculating because I get some weird stuff @Yaddle

Comment: You miscalculated in your first claim, the limit there is $-1/2.$

Comment: @zhw. You're right. I corrected it.